# ServletContext in JUnit is missing in PostContruct-Method

Tags: java, spring, junit

I'm one of the newbies to spring. So my problem is this, that I have a RestController like this, which is using a third lib, that uses static methods:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/my/rest/controller")
public class MyRestController
{
    @PostConstruct
    public void initThirdLib()
    {
        ThirdLibClassA.doSomeInitStuff();
    }
    
    // methods with @RequestMapping
}
```

This works fine, as I ran the MVC app itself. But when I run the Tests it gives an Exception from my `initThirdLib()`-Method, which is going back, that the third-lib inside wants a valid object of `javax.servlet.ServletContext`. I've found the way to provide it to the lib by calling a method `ThirdLibClassB.setContext( servletContext )`.

But when I do so, I found out, that the `@PostConstruct`-method is called before my test mocking-setup is called.

My test looks like:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK)
class MyTest 
{
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup()
    {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
        ServletContext servletContext = this.wac.getServletContext();
        ThirdLibClassB.setContext( servletContext );
        wac.getBean( MyRestController.class ).initThirdLib();
    }
}
```

If I catch the Exception from `initThirdLib()` it still will be thrown while `@PostConstruct` and will success within the manualy call withing the test.

But is there a way to provide the `servletContext` before the `@PostConstruct`-call to avoid the Exception-Handling?

Comment: Ofcourse it will throw an exception. The exception will be thrown even before the `setup` method will be called. Add `@AutoconfigureMockMvc` and `@Autowire` to `MockMvc` and remove your `setup` method.

Comment: @M.Deinum: you mean `@Autowired`, right? For `@AutoconfigureMockMvc` my compiler says it's disallowed at this location

Comment: `@AutuconfigureMockMvc` needs to go on your class next to `@SpringBootTest`.

Comment: no - didn't worked

Comment: Then your regular application must be doing something else as compared to a test. That being said, calling a static method from the `@Before` might be troublesome, as you have no guarantee that setup of the other class has been done.